# How to read a deserialized json to display in xamarin

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, deserialization

I have this deserialized json because i want to read every single item in this json to display in a listview

```
[
    {
        "nom": "Gestión y Admon. de Proyectos",
        "peri": "0985",
        "crse_id": "013981",
        "horario": [
            {
                "feci": "2019-01-21",
                "hora": "16:00 - 18:00",
                "saln": "EG-3.1",
                "fecf": "2019-05-18",
                "doc": "Carlos Mario Vélez Velásquez",
                "dia": "4 "
            }
        ],
        "notas": [],
        "parciales": []
    },
    {
        "nom": "Análisis y Diseño de Algoritmo",
        "peri": "0985",
        "crse_id": "012853",
        "horario": [
            {
                "feci": "2019-01-21",
                "hora": "09:00 - 11:00",
                "saln": "PL-3.2",
                "fecf": "2019-05-11",
                "doc": "MIGUEL ANGEL ROMERO GONZALEZ",
                "dia": "2 "
            },
            {
                "feci": "2019-01-21",
                "hora": "09:00 - 11:00",
                "saln": "PL-3.1",
                "fecf": "2019-05-11",
                "doc": "HERNAN CAMILO ROCHA NIÑO",
                "dia": "4 "
            }
        ],
        "notas": [],
        "parciales": []
    }
]
```

And i want to read in a cycle and display the content of cada object in the array .
Im using XAMARIN and this is my function but doesnt No work

```
 var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<materias>>(content);

            if (content != null)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("mensaje", Items.nom, "ok");
                foreach (var materia in Items)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("materia", , "ok");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errorLog.Text = "Ups No se pudo Conectar Al servidor";


            }
```

Comment: I Have my class Materias with all this parameters

Comment: If it's deserialized, it's no longer JSON. You'll need to be a bit more clear on what "doesn't work" means. Do you get an error? It would also make it easier to answer your question if you included the definition of `materias`. Note that C# is case sensitive, so that's not the same thing as `Materias`...

Comment: that code will not even compile. Items is a List<T>, it has no property "nom", and DisplayAlert is missing an argument. Please read up on [mcve] before posting

Comment: Well, as Jason mentioned it's pretty hard to know exactly what the problem is based on your question.  That aside, why exactly are you checking content isn't null after you're deserialize it?  Is perhaps the problem you're tying to deserialize null?  What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a correct definition for the `materias` class, your `Items` reference will point to a list of `materias` objects. This means that the following line won't work because it tries to access `materias` property while being a list.

```
    await DisplayAlert("mensaje", Items.nom, "ok");
```

If you want to access a property, access it in your while loop:

```
var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<materias>>(content);

// no need to check `content` because here you work with `Items` already
if (Items != null)
{
    // Count will show you number of records deserilized
    await DisplayAlert("mensaje", Items.Count, "ok");
    foreach (var materia in Items)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("materia", materia.nom, "ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: It Doesnt Work. This is my class materias  -> public class materias
    {
        public string nom { get; set; }
        public string peri { get; set; }
        public string coda { get; set; }
        public string Strm { get; set; }
        public string notp { get; set; }
        public string porci { get; set; }
        public string class_section { get; set; }
        public string crse_id { get; set; }
        public List<Horario> horario { get; set; }
        public List<object> notas { get; set; }
        public List<object> parciales { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @AndersonLaverde appreciate! Could you please add this definition to the original question, and I noticed you were able to solve the issue, could you please specify what was the specific issue so others could benefit from the question